How can I make static class members be accepted by eslint9?
For our Cypress E2E testing we are using page-objects as below (https://github.com/OWASP/wrongsecrets/blob/master/src/test/e2e/cypress/pages/homePage.js):
export default class HomePage {
  static CHALLENGE_TABLE = 'challenge-overview'
  static CHALLENGE_TABLE_ROW = 'challenge-row'
  static CHALLENGE_0_COMPLETED = '"challenge-0_completed-link"'
  static TOTAL_SCORE = 'total-score'
}

when I run eslint9, I get:
/home/runner/work/wrongsecrets/wrongsecrets/src/test/e2e/cypress/pages/homePage.js
  2:26  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =

While my eslint.config.mjs is:
import { FlatCompat } from '@eslint/eslintrc'
import mochaPlugin from 'eslint-plugin-mocha'
import globals from "globals";
const compat = new FlatCompat()
export default [
  {
    languageOptions: {
      ecmaVersion: 2022,
      sourceType: "commonjs",
      globals:{
        ...globals.browser
      }
    },
  },
  mochaPlugin.configs.flat.recommended, {
    rules: {
      'mocha/no-exclusive-tests': 'error',
      'mocha/no-skipped-tests': 'error',
      'mocha/no-mocha-arrows': 'off'
    }
  },
  ...compat.config(
    {
      extends: ['plugin:cypress/recommended'],
      rules: {
        'cypress/no-unnecessary-waiting': 'off'
      }
    })
]

What is wrong with my eslint.config.mjs? How can I make Eslint accept static properties? Or are my static properties no longer defined properly? Can you please help me?

Please do not abuse class syntax! There is no reason to have a class with only static fields that you never instantiate. Just write export default const HomePage = {   CHALLENGE_TABLE: 'challenge-overview',   CHALLENGE_TABLE_ROW: 'challenge-row',   CHALLENGE_0_COMPLETED: '"challenge-0_completed-link"',   TOTAL_SCORE: 'total-score' }

The eslint config needs to use babel as a parser if static properties are being used. You can do this in the below format in a flat config system. I have used babel with no config.
import { FlatCompat } from '@eslint/eslintrc';
import mochaPlugin from 'eslint-plugin-mocha';
import globals from 'globals';
import babelParser from "@babel/eslint-parser";

const compat = new FlatCompat();

export default [
  {
    languageOptions: {
      ecmaVersion: 2022,
      sourceType: 'module',
      globals: {
        ...globals.browser,
      },
      parser: babelParser,
      parserOptions: {
        requireConfigFile: false,
        babelOptions: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
        },
      },
    },
  },
  mochaPlugin.configs.flat.recommended,
  {
    rules: {
      'mocha/no-exclusive-tests': 'error',
      'mocha/no-skipped-tests': 'error',
      'mocha/no-mocha-arrows': 'off',
    },
  },
  ...compat.config({
    extends: ['plugin:cypress/recommended'],
    rules: {
      'cypress/no-unnecessary-waiting': 'off',
    },
  }),
];

You can read more here https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/migration-guide#custom-parsers . I hope this helps!
